# Sources for what happened to Avraham’s Converts?

Tags: tanach, conversion-to-judaism, abraham

In Bereishis (12:5 and in Rashi) we see that Avraham converted people in Charan, and then took them with him to Kena’an. 
Do we know what happened to them?

• When Avraham and Lot separated, who did they go with?

• If with Lot, did they die in the war between the five and four kings, or in the destruction of S’dom?

• If with Avraham, did they go with him in his travels?

• Did they (their children) intermarry with Avraham’s family?

• Did they go down to Egypt? (among the non-counted, like the wives of Ya’acov’s sons.)

• Did they come out again, and if so, as the eirev rav or as part of B’nei Yisrael?

Obviously these questions can continue going down the generations until nowadays, but I feel these will be easier to trace.

Sourced answers please. A timeline would be helpful.

Comment: I realize that this looks like too many questions, but I’m  really just looking for anything to do with the converts, with emphasis on these events.

Comment: Maybe, but that question has no sources answers, which I specifically asked for.

Comment: Please reopen. I specifically asked for sources, while shmuel brin did not, and therefore did not get sourced answers.

Comment: No, if you want sources you should name the question "Sources for X", and not "What happened?"

Comment: @Al Berko I’ve changed the question

Comment: Again please reopen, as I’ve changed the question enough that it is not answered by the “duplicate” @DonielF sabbahillel, Al Berko, mbloch, and Joel K

Answer (score -1):

Even if that's a dupe I'll answer it here:

1. It is not clear at all that Avraham was converting into Judaism, indeed he might only turn them into Ger Toshav - abandoning idolatry and accepting the 7 Noahide Mitzvos. So they were never real Jews.
2. Even if we say that he was truly converting them into full-fledged Jews, Before Matan Torah there was no "Jewish people" and no continuity from mother/father to child. Seemingly everyone had to accept Judaism and [sort of] convert.
3. Avraham's converts didn't form a nation and they merely dispersed.

Comment: “Sources answers please”! I’m not looking for conjecture, if I was this would be a duplicate with answers.

Comment: 1. The answer is not only for your eyes only, this site is a public domain. Many (some) prefer reason over authority. 2. This is based on my oral tradition - I read books, I ask Rabbis. Here I just summarize the various approaches.

Comment: Look at the Accepted answer of Shalom - that got +7 and accepted, and you're talking sources. Reopen your question immediately!

Comment: Which is why I asked for sources. Shalom’s answer is very good, but unsourced. Your answer would be better suited to that question. @Al Berko

Comment: Let me ask you, say קרני שור says like my #1 - does it help you to understand?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful.